# Make the segments pairwise disjoint from left End

Tags: algorithm

I am provided with M segments of form [L,R] of N elements of an array.I need to change these segments in such a way that all segments have pairwise distinct left ends.

Example : Let suppose we have 5 elements in array and we have 4 segments : [1,2],[1,3],[2,4] and [4,5] then after making all the left ends pairwise disjoint we have [1,2],[3,3],[2,4] and [4,5].Here all segments have different left ends

The main question is to make all pairs pairwise disjoint from left end.Like if their are two overlapping pairs say [1,3] and [1,4] then change them to [1,3] and [4,4].Whats the best approach to handle it?

Answer (score 0):

This is a greedy solution sketched below. First, sort the segments based on their left end and break the ties based on their right ends. Now, move through the array of segments. If left end of current segment coincides with the previous one, just increase the current segment by 1. If left end of current segment is less than the previous one, then make the left end of current segment = `left_end_of_previous_segment+1`. Otherwise leave the left end as it is. Now, if we change the left end of any segment, make sure the right end is at least as large as the left end. This algorithm takes O(NlgN + N) time

By the way, **If you can change any end points and there's no condition on moving**, you can easily do this trick. Just run for loop and make all the left ends and right ends = i+1

```
for(int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    left[i]  = i+1;
    right[i] = i+1;
}
```

The above code ensures all left end will be distinct but I think there's some other conditions you've missed, probably? Like, you're not allowed to move right end?

Comment: yeah,we cant move the right end.and isnt it possible that after increasing left end by +1 it become now equal to left end of some other segment?

Comment: well, note that our segments are initially sorted based on their left ends. So say, we increase ith segments left end by 1 and the new left end of ith segment collides with the left end of i+1st segment. Don't worry about this because in the next iteration i+1st segment will compare its left end and will change accordingly.

By the way, if we're not allowed to move right end of any segment then there might be cases where the target is impossible to achieve.